# Need a self. method on a Rails model using Acts_as_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, methods

I am still newer to Rails... I need to write a self.method on my Product model to find the next Product per position.  I am showing 1 Product on a page, and want the next one in the list.

```
def self.next_product
product = Product. # current product.position +1
end
```

obviously this won't work... I am still new to writing methods.  anyone?

I am using Rbates Railscast 147 and Acts_as_list, I need to figure out how to get the next product

thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

acts_as_list already adds methods for getting the next and previous items, they are called **higher_item** (position - 1) and **lower_item** (position + 1). However, they are instance methods, not class methods (self.) because to find "the next item" in a list, you need to start with an item (an instance of the Product class), not the Product class itself.

```
=> p = Product.first
<Product id: 1, position: 1>
=> p.lower_item
<Product id: 2, position: 2>
```

- See the [acts_as_list documentation](http://rdoc.info/projects/rails/acts_as_list) for descriptions of the methods it adds to your class.
- See [this blog post](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) for a description of class and instance methods in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks so much for that info.  So I would write a simple instance variable in the controller, @product = Product.find(:first :conditions {position first})

then in the view just pull that instance variable, then setup a link_to with that instance method?  

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product
 def next_product
   lower_item or self
 end
 def previous_product
   higher_item or self
 end
end

link_to "Next", product_path(@product.next_item) 

link_to "Previous", product_path(@product.previous_item)
```